# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at an.html:895

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i hope anyone can help me,

In google chrome Console, the error showing is

> ### Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at examples.html:895
>
> but this error is looping Up to thousands of times, The code I put
> before `</body>`

its my code

```
 function dezText(words, id) {
    'use strict';
    var visible = true;
    var letterCount = 1;
    var x = 1;
    var waiting = false;
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    window.setInterval(function() {

        if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var usedWord = words.shift();
                words.push(usedWord);
                x = 1;
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 500)
        } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                x = -1;
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
        } else if (waiting === false) {
            target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
            letterCount += x;
        }
    }, 70)
}
```

Comment: That error message implies that `target` is `null`, which it would be if `document.getElementById(id)` didn't find an element with the specified ID. How/where do you call the `dezText()` function? *"but this error is looping Up to thousands of times"* - Yes, because the line giving the error is in the anonymous function being called every 70ms by `setInterval`.

Comment: @nnnnnn what do u mean `innerHTML` is not specified ID guys ?

Comment: Please produce more information how you call your `dezText` function

Comment: I mean that the sixth line of the `dezText()` function that has `document.getElementById(id)` is *not* finding an element with the specified `id` value, and that's what in turn leads to the error message you're getting.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev i call the `dezText` is `dezText(['We Are Coming Soon', 'We Are Coming Soon'], "text");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id is send null in your function
for remove errors in console you can set condition in your function that check the "id" is null or has value and if id has value run other codes

```
     function dezText(words, id) {
        'use strict';
if(id){
        var visible = true;
        var letterCount = 1;
        var x = 1;
        var waiting = false;
        var target = document.getElementById(id);
        window.setInterval(function() {

            if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
                waiting = true;
                target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    var usedWord = words.shift();
                    words.push(usedWord);
                    x = 1;
                    letterCount += x;
                    waiting = false;
                }, 500)
            } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
                waiting = true;
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    x = -1;
                    letterCount += x;
                    waiting = false;
                }, 1000)
            } else if (waiting === false) {
                target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
                letterCount += x;
            }
        }, 70)
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### My Problem is solved
>
> thanks everybody, thanks stacnk overvlow.

Thanks very much dude, but I use my code, and its work for me and my problen is solved

```
 function dezText(words, id) {
    'use strict';
if($('#'+id).length > 0)
{
    var visible = true;
    var letterCount = 1;
    var x = 1;
    var waiting = false;
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    window.setInterval(function() {

        if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var usedWord = words.shift();
                words.push(usedWord);
                x = 1;
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 500)
        } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
            waiting = true;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                x = -1;
                letterCount += x;
                waiting = false;
            }, 1000)
        } else if (waiting === false) {
            target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
            letterCount += x;
        }
    }, 70)
}
```

}